# Why does Xcode 7 keep losing constraints and losing preview window configurations?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, autolayout, xcode7

My Xcode 7.0.1 constraints keep disappearing randomly. I'll put loving care into designing a nice layout and using the storyboard Preview window, and randomly my constraints just disappear. I've noticed that at the same time, my storyboard Preview window loses the configurations I've chosen. So let's say I'm looking at a landscape view on 4-inch iPhone and landscape iPad, all of a sudden they've both switched to portrait, and all my constraints have disappeared with no explanation. This is driving me crazy. Sometimes it happens at random, but there are some ways to reproduce it (e.g. if you switch over to your assets folder and look at a specific asset resolution, then back to your storyboard, boom - one or more constraints will disappear (at least on my system) and the preview window device settings are modified.

Comment: Better upgrade to Xcode 7.1

Comment: Thanks; that seems to have helped a lot. There are still some issues with the preview window losing settings, but my constraints seems to be more stable now. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I'm running Xcode 7.1.1 and still having problems with constraints... I set up all of them correctly and after a restart I got tons of warnings... Xcode loses the correct positions, so I need to update all of them again.

Comment: Try 7.2. It's been pretty stable for me